# Why would I combine a private constructor with a static nested class?

Tags: java, inner-classes

I'm currently digging a little bit into accessibility of Java classes. While there is a varity of possibilities to [define classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html), I wonder about a use case for the example below.

Basically, the constructor of `AnotherClass` is private. However, `AnotherClass` has a *static nested class*, which is accessible within the `PublicClass` class.

It's just something I came up with out of curiosity, but as it actually works, I wonder, why would I ever use something like this?

**Example**

```
public class PublicClass {  
    public PublicClass() {
        AnotherClass.AnotherInnerClass innerClass = new AnotherClass.AnotherInnerClass();
        innerClass.anotherTest();
    }
}


class AnotherClass{
    /**
     * Private constructor - class cannot be instantiated within PublicClass.
     */
    private AnotherClass(){

    }

    /**
     * Static inner class - can still be accessed within package.
     */
    static class AnotherInnerClass{
        public void anotherTest(){
            System.out.println("Called another test.");
        }
    }
}
```

**Note** those classes are within the same file.

**Output**

```
Called another test.
```

Comment: *why would I ever use something like this?* It's ugly. Just because you **can** write something, doesn't mean you ***should***.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I'm just wondering if there are any uses cases at all - as in _Did you ever came across such code in a serious project?_

Comment: See my answer below. I am currently using it in a use case where my `Bar` gets passed around a lot, since it's parameters can't be set in a single class. By passing around the builder instead of the object itself I can check if all the parameters are set on calling the `Builder.build()` function, so I know for sure that everything is set correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `AnotherInnerClass` CAN use the private constructor of `AnotherClass`. This is used for example in the [Builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern), which is something along the lines of this:

```
public class Foo {  
    public Foo() {
        Bar.Builder barBuilder = new Bar.Builder();
        Bar bar = barBuilder.build();
    }
}


public class Bar{
    private Bar(..){

    }

    static class Builder{
        public Bar build(){
            return new Bar(..);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After your comment above, I consider your example as a valid reason to create a structure like this. Also, I now consider my example (which is not using the builder pattern) as a _noone-would-ever-use-this_ structure.